# Apply CSS-Style to HTML classes created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply the style form my CSS file to a HTML class which I created with Javascript.

My Code looks like this
`

```
    socket.on('chat', function (data) {
        feedback.innerHTML = '';
        var mewTime = document.createElement("span")
        mewTime.class = "chatTime";
        mewTime.text = data.currentTime;

        console.log(mewTime);

        var userName = createUser(data, mewTime);

        var content = document.createElement("span")
        content.class = "messageContent"
        content.append(data.messageInput)

        var message = document.createElement("div")
        message.class = "message";
        message.append(userName[0].outerHTML);
        message.append(mewTime);
        message.append(document.createElement("br"))
        message.append(content);

        output.append(message);

        currentTime = '';
        messageInput.focus();
    });

function createUser(data, time){
    if(time === null){
        var userName = $('<span class="userNameOnline"/>');
        userName.text(data);  
    } else{
        var userName = $('<span class="userName"/>')
            .text(data.username + ' ' + time.text);
    }
    console.log(userName);
    return userName;
}

// CSS
.message{
color: red;
}

.userName {
color: blue;
}
```

`

I can access the text in the message but I can't style it with my CSS.

I tried to use `.outerHTML`, `.innerHTML`, `.text`.
On the console it shows that the class is correctly set.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Which element do you want to change? Have you tried `element.className = "message"`?

Comment: But isn't it possible that my style.css file applys the style to it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList `classList` is the html5 way to do it. Otherwise you should use the `className` property as nick proposed. This way the style of your css will be applied to the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `classList.add('')` instead of `class = ''`. You can find more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp).

Here's a basic example:

```js
   
var message = document.createElement("div")
message.classList.add("message")


document.getElementById("output").append(message);
```

```css
.message {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

In your code you can change it to the following and it should work:

```
var message = document.createElement("div")
message.classList.add("message")
message.append(userName[0].outerHTML);
message.append(mewTime);
message.append(document.createElement("br"))
message.append(content);

output.append(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.setAttribute("attributeName", "value of attribute")` or you can also use `.className` instead of a normal `class`. So for your example we can have something like:

```
var mewTime = document.createElement("span");
mewTime.setAttribute("class", "chatTime");
```

OR

```
var mewTime = document.createElement("span");
mewTime.className = "chatTime"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("divTest").classList.add('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='divTest'>
      test
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should use classList: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

You could use as below example to apply CSS on HTML element in Javascript:

```
yourElement.style.border= "1px solid red";
```

Comment: Thank you. But i want to have all my styling in one file and not in my script file and my css file. Is this possiple?

Comment: Yes why not, but I didnt understand what you want to exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
function myFunction() {
var message = document.createElement("span");
message.innerHTML = "Test"
        message.className = "message";
        
         document.body.appendChild(message);
}
```

```css
.message{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Create</button>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the method to do that.

```
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.setAttribute("class", "className");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change **class** to **className**, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
    mewTime.className = "chatTime";

    content.className = "messageContent"

    message.className = "message";
```